# SQlite 3.8.8 SPACE() function alternative

Tags: function, sqlite

Is there a way to generate blank spaces in SQLite in the same way as we do in MS SQL using SPACE function?

Example:

```
SELECT SPACE(field * 4) FROM test
```

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [printf](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#printf) function to pad an empty string to the desired width:

```
SELECT printf('%*s', 4, '');
```